# Pythonic way to map yyyymm formated column into a numeric column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Sorry if it's not totally clear in the title, but the point is I have a Pandas `DataFrame` with the following `Date` column:

```
 Date
201611
201612
201701
```

And I want to map that so I have a period column that takes value 1 for the first period, and then starts counting one by one until the last period, like this:

```
 Date     Period
201611      1
201612      2
201701      3
```

I achieved what I want doing this:

```
dic_t={}
for n,t in enumerate(sorted(df.Date.unique())):
    dic_t[t]=n+1
df['Period']=df.Date.map(dic_t)
```

But it doesn't seem too pythonic. I guess I could achieve something similar using dictionary comprehensions, but I'm not good at them **yet**.

Any ideas?

Comment: is `Period == month`? you haven't really given us a ton of information here.

Comment: How is the current data stored? Is this in Pandas? Is it in a dictionary? CSV? And what are 'periods'? Months? And what are you trying to ultimately output? A dictionary?

Comment: Could be Moon's revolution duration (~27 days) :d

Comment: My bad. I edited the original post so it better explains the problem.

Comment: So based off your edits, a 'period' is one month and it starts at an arbitrary month (Nov 2016)? So Dec 2016 is 2, Jan 2017 is 3, Feb 2017 is 4? etc...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking to do. As stated, I can achieve that, only that the way I've done it, I find it not very pythonic, and I would like to improve my python skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) can sort a list of items and return unique integer labels:

```
In [209]: pd.factorize(['201611','201612','201701','201702','201704','201612'], sort=True)[0]+1
Out[209]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2])
```

Therefore you could use

```
df['Period'] = pd.factorize(df['Date'], sort=True)[0] + 1
```

---

`pd.factorize` returns both an array of labels and an array of unique values:

```
In [210]: pd.factorize(['201611','201612','201701','201702','201704','201612'], sort=True)
Out[210]: 
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]),
 array(['201611', '201612', '201701', '201702', '201704'], dtype=object))
```

Since, in this question, it appears you only want the labels, I used `pd.factorize(...)[0]` to obtain just the labels.

Comment: This is very interesting. Just a note to the author of the question @JuanC: if there are missing periods in the data (for example, no rows for march 2017) then it will skip that period in the enumeration and the period number might not be what was expected.

Comment: @Ralf: Yes, but it is consistent with the code JuanC posted.

Comment: This is the kind of discoveries I love to make when asking in SO, had no idea about `pd.factorize`. My data has no gaps, indeed, but it's nice to know I have to take that into account for future problems. Thanks to both of you !

Answer (score 1):

So, based on the info from the question and the comments, the enumeration of the periods (combinations of year and month) should start at the first period that is present in the dataframe.

For that purpose, your code works just fine. If you think that `dict` comprehensions look "more pythonic", you could express that as:

```
period_dict = {
    period: i+1
    for i, period in enumerate(sorted(df.Date.unique()))}
df['Period'] = df.Date.map(period_dict)
```

---

Just note: with this method, if for some reason there aren't any datapoints for a month after the start month, that month will not have a period number assigned for it.
For example, if you have no data for march 2017, then:

```
 Date     Period
201611      1
201612      2
201701      3
201702      4
201704      5       <== April is period 5 and not 6
```

If you need to generate the full enumeration for all possible periods, use something like this:

```
start_year = 2016
end_year = 2018
period_list = [
    y*100 + m
    for y in range(start_year, end_year+1)
    for m in range(1, 13)]
period_dict = {
    period: i+1
    for i, period in enumerate(period_list)}

df['Period'] = df.Date.map(period_dict)
```